# How to compare two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

I have two dates, start date and end date. I am comparing them like this:

```
var fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
var throughDate = $("#throughDate").val();

if (startdate >= enddate) {
    alert('start date cannot be greater then end date')
}
```

It gives the correct result... the only problem is when I compare the dates 01/01/2013 and 01/01/2014.

How can I correctly compare dates in JavaScript?

Comment: For the future: http://bit.ly/QcITo9

Answer (score 7):

You can use this to get the comparison:

```
if (new Date(startDate) > new Date(endDate))
```

Using [new Date(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) parses the value and converts it to a Date object.

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing strings. You need to convert them to dates first. You can do so by splitting your string and constructing a [new Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])
```

Depending on you date format it would look like

```
var parts = "01/01/2013".split("/");
var myDate = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
      var toDate = $("#throughDate").val();

    //Detailed check for valid date ranges
        //if your date is like 09-09-2012
    var frommonthfield = fromDate.split("-")[1];
    var fromdayfield = fromDate.split("-")[0];
    var fromyearfield = fromDate.split("-")[2];


    var tomonthfield = toDate.split("-")[1];
    var todayfield = toDate.split("-")[0];
    var toyearfield = toDate.split("-")[2];


    var fromDate = new Date(fromyearfield, frommonthfield-1, fromdayfield);
    var toDate = new Date(toyearfield, tomonthfield-1, todayfield);

    if(fromDate.getTime() > today.getTime()){
        alert("from Date should be less than today")
        return;
    }
    if(toDate.getTime() > today.getTime()){
        alert("to Date should be less than today")
        return;
    }
    if(fromDate.getTime() > toDate.getTime()){
        alert("from date should be less than to date")
        return;
    }
```